# Firebase snapshot.foreach runs every time when the component get mounted in react native

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native

I am trying to make a timeline of photos in react native with firebase. My intention is that when the user starts the app he / she has to press a button to retrieve the data. This looks like this:

in View:

```
 <TouchableOpacity onPress={() =>this.getMessagesNew(0)}><Text>Haal berichten op</Text></TouchableOpacity>
```

The function:

```
 getMessagesNew(key){
    
      console.log('triggerd')
    
      this.setState({
    amountVideos: 0,
    downloadedVideos:0,
   
  })

  this.messages = [];



  var orders =  firebase.database().ref('messages/'+key+'/posts').orderByChild('post').limitToLast(3);
  orders.on('value', snapshot => {
  
    snapshot.forEach( (order) => {
      console.log('triggerd in loop')
      let state = order.val();
      if(state != null){
        var newelement = {date: state.date, function: state.function,image:state.image,name: state.name,  text: state.text, type:state.type, post: state.post,};
        if(newelement.type == false){
          this.setState({amountVideos: this.state.amountVideos+1})
          this.downloadImage(newelement);
        }else{
          messages.push(newelement);
          if(this.state.amountVideos == 0){
            this.setState({
              loading: false,
              messagesAvailable: true,
              refresh: this.state.refresh+1,
            })
          }else{
            console.log('videos laden');
            this.setState({
              refresh: this.state.refresh+1
            })
          }
           console.log('message local val'+this.messages);
           console.log('message state val'+this.state.messages);
 
        }
          
      }else{
        this.setState({
          messagesAvailable: false,
        })
      }
    });
   

})

  

   }
```

the function: this.getMessagesNew () gets the last three messages from firebase. This works without any effort.

But the app also allows the user to upload photos to firebase. That all works, and after uploading the user is navigated back to the main screen. And here it goes wrong, the just uploaded image is already shown. While this is not the intention.

I want the user to have to press a button again to retrieve the new photos.

I know that the first part of the function is not reloaded but from the `snapshot.foreach`.

Is there any way to stop this process and make it happen only when a button is pressed?

Answer (score 0):

you are subscribing to the changes using `orders.on('value', ...)` thats why things are getting synced whenever you upload an image so for achieving the behaviour get the value once from the database using `orders.once('value', ...)` and then everything ll work as you expect

here i m rewriting your code

```
getMessagesNew(key){
  console.log('triggerd');
  this.setState({
      amountVideos: 0,
      downloadedVideos:0
  });

  this.messages = [];
  var orders = firebase.database().ref('messages/'+key+'/posts').orderByChild('post').limitToLast(3);
  orders.once('value', snapshot => { // observe i have changed "on" to "once"

  snapshot.forEach( (order) => {
      console.log('triggerd in loop')
      let state = order.val();
      if(state != null){
        var newelement = {date: state.date, function: state.function,image:state.image,name: state.name,  text: state.text, type:state.type, post: state.post,};
    if(newelement.type == false){
      this.setState({amountVideos: this.state.amountVideos+1})
      this.downloadImage(newelement);
    }else{
      messages.push(newelement);
      if(this.state.amountVideos == 0){
        this.setState({
          loading: false,
          messagesAvailable: true,
          refresh: this.state.refresh+1,
        })
      }else{
        console.log('videos laden');
        this.setState({
          refresh: this.state.refresh+1
        })
      }
       console.log('message local val'+this.messages);
       console.log('message state val'+this.state.messages);

    }
      
  }else{
    this.setState({
      messagesAvailable: false,
    })
  }
});


})
```

}